# Packaging a Python script on Linux into a Windows executable

Tags: python, linux, windows, py2exe

I have a Python script that I'd like to compile into a Windows executable. Now, `py2exe` works fine from Windows, but I'd like to be able to run this from Linux. I *do* have Windows on my development machine, but Linux is my primary dev platform and I'm getting kind of sick of rebooting into Windows just to create the `.exe`. Nor do I want to have to buy a second Windows license to run in a virtual machine such as VirtualBox. Any ideas?

PS: I am aware that `py2exe` doesn't exactly compile the python file as much as package your script with the Python interpreter. But either way, the result is that you don't need Python installed to run the script.

Comment: When I need something Windows-only (e.g. IE or testing NSIS install packages), I use a virtual machine with Windows; Virtualbox works great and no rebooting is necessary. Of course, this is just side-stepping the issue.

Comment: Ah, but _technically_ you require two licences of Windows for this...

Comment: Do I? How so? The host OS is not Windows in my case, only the guest is.

Comment: @Piskvor In order to not need two licenses, one for bare metal and one for VirtualBox, the asker would have to first uninstall Windows from bare metal and install it in VirtualBox. I'm not sure whether an OEM license even allows that.

Comment: Where did an OEM license requirement  come from? I see no mention in the question; do not assume too much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you look at [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

It seems that versions through 1.4 support cross-compilation (support was removed in 1.5+). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605479/2639936) for how to do it with PyInstaller 1.5+ under Wine.

[Documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/CHANGES-1.html#id3) says:

> Add support for cross-compilation: PyInstaller is now able to build Windows executables when running under Linux. See documentation for more details.

I didn't try it myself.

I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, that works: http://groups.google.com/group/pyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/2884993f9b070968

Comment: Aargh! This _should_ work, but the bloody thing only supports python 2.6 on *NIXes and my script requires python 2.6 to work... Looks like more effort than it's worth... I guess I just need to plan my build cycles so I only reboot into Windows a minimum number of times...

Comment: @Chinmay: there was a pywin26 branch of pyinstaller that has been merged into the trunk. So, if you are the daring kind of person, you can check out the trunk using `svn co http://svn.pyinstaller.org/trunk pyinstaller-trunk` and it *should* work with 2.6 on Windows.

Comment: I will give this a try. The immediate problem has been solved by rebooting into Windows, but this _is_ likely to crop up fairly often now that I've moved almost completely over to Linux. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: this feature is being taken out: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/PyInstaller/linux$20windows/pyinstaller/veq3BlA_Bns

Comment: SO messes up the previous link. Anyway in that thread the author says "I'm the one who implemented this feature some time ago. And I'm going to remove it in the near future, since it does one work half."

Comment: For future visitors, here's the working link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pyinstaller/veq3BlA_Bns

Comment: It seems some users were able to successfully compile a Windows exe on Linux using pyInstaller under Wine. You might give it a try.

Comment: As is mentioned by @hoju, this feature is removed from PyInstaller since 1.5. See http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/FAQ#Features: "In version 1.4 we had build in some support for this, but it showed to work only half. It would require some Windows system on another partition and would only work for pure Python programs. As soon as you want a decent GUI (gtk, qt, wx), you would need to install Windows libraries anyhow. So it's much easier to just use Wine."

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi I make it, please check my answer.

Comment: PyInstaller doesn't support cross-compilation. Wine is for that.

Comment: It has been said in FAQ "No, this is not supported. Please use Wine for this, PyInstaller runs fine in Wine"

Comment: Answer invalid in 2020

Answer (score 46):

As mentioned by other answerers, the cross-compilation feature is removed from [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) since `1.5`. Here, show how to package a Windows executable from Python scripts using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) under [wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)).

### Step 1: Install wine and Python

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wine msiexec /i python-2.7.10.msi /L*v log.txt
```

PS:

- Newer Python versions already include `pip` (is used to install `pyinstaller`). Download Python installation package from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (e.g., `python-2.7.10.msi`)
- For macos users, use `brew cask install xquartz wine-stable`.

### Step 2: Install PyInstaller on wine

```
$ cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Python27
$ wine python.exe Scripts/pip.exe install pyinstaller

Successfully installed pyinstaller-3.1.1 pypiwin32-219
```

### Step 3: Package Python scripts

Package Python scripts (e.g., `HelloWorld.py`) with `pyinstaller`.

```
$ wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Python27/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe --onefile HelloWorld.py

# filename: HelloWorld.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print('Hello World!')
```

The Windows executable file is located in `dist/`.

```
$ wine dist/HelloWorld.exe 
Hello World!
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1e24e5b8) stub
```

Refer to [here](http://sparkandshine.net/en/build-a-windows-executable-from-python-scripts-on-linux/) for the detailed description.

Comment: You will have to install all the dependencies in wine too (though you might have it in Ubuntu). __Make sure that your application run using command__ `wine python appli.py`

Comment: Useless now since there is no way to install python 3 on wine

Comment: There is also a way to install python in wine if you have no .msi file https://askubuntu.com/questions/678277/how-to-install-python3-in-wine

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.makeworld.space/2021/10/linux-wine-pyinstaller.html) on how to do this with PyInstaller. Here's the summary:

- How to create EXEs for Python on Linux, using PyInstaller and WINE

  - Download Python 3.8 Windows installer
  - `wine python-3.8.9.exe`, then see instructions below
  - `wine C:/Python38/python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`
  - `wine C:/Python38/python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt`, and `requirements.txt` should include PyInstaller itself
  - `wine C:/Python38/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe ...`
  - All done!

Installing Python 3.8 in Wine:

1. Check "Add Python 3.8 to PATH"
2. Click "Customize installation
3. Click "Next"
4. Click "Install for all users"
5. Set the install location as `C:\\Python38`
6. Click "Install"
7. Close the window.

---

Feel free to read the post to get more details.

Answer (score 3):

You could run Windows in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) in order to run py2exe. VBox offers a powerful command-line client for automating tasks, so it something that you could likely integrate into your development process with ease.

Comment: That would technically require me to have a second Windows licence, something I would rather not get involved in. But +1 anyway.

Comment: or you could use a crack for windows, if you want, just for test purpose

Comment: you could also buy a whole new computer with windows

Answer (score 3):

Tested on Platform: Kubuntu 20.04, wine 6.0, python38

### Download wine and python

1. Download windows version of python from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/
2. Install wine
   `sudo apt install wine`
3. Open your terminal and run
   `wine the-python-exe-you-downloaded`
4. Run
   `find ~/.wine -name pip.exe`
   this will give you the pip path:

`/home/yourusername/.wine/drive_c/users/yourusername/Local Settings/Application Data/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts/pip.exe`

### Install pyinstaller

Run `wine /home/yourusername/.wine/drive_c/users/yourusername/Local\ Settings/Application\ Data/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts/pip.exe install pyinstaller`

### Package your file

Find installation path

`find ~/.wine -name pyinstaller.exe`

`wine /home/yourusernmae/.wine/drive_c/users/yourusername/Local\ Settings/Application\ Data/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe --onefile yourpythonfile`

Comment: This is a very helpful answer to me because you have shown me how to find the wines pyinstaller.exe location. 
If anyone is still facing any issues while using this output location then please check if there is any file that contains spaces. Just enclose them with quotes and it will work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested py2exe inside of wine, and it does function.  You'll need to install python in wine for it to work, or if you only use the standard libarary, you can bundle py2exe with py2exe from the windows machine and then use it in wine.  Just keep in mind you need the same version of the ms visual C libraries in wine as were used to compile python or things won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I works fine as kaptaan wrote above:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67857785/23262833

Tested on platform: Ubuntu 22.04, Wine 9.0, Python 3.12

Download wine 9.0 from winehq download page - https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu (ubuntu repositories has available wine 6.0).

You can run Pyinstaller to build windows .exe app;
You can run Innosetup to create an installer for your windows aplication.