# Is it possible to generate an executable for Windows using bbfreeze (python) on a Linux platform? If so, how?

Tags: python, linux

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable). The answer there suggests using PyInstaller. I'm looking at PyInstaller documentation. In the meanwhile, if somebody could specify how this could be done using bbfreeze that would be great, since we already have a deployment system in place that uses bbfreeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not terribly likely. If I were you I would try to use the Windows PY2EXE inside WINE. If it works, you are golden, if not head to your local used laptops flea market and get an old Windows XP machine to do the job.