# is there any way to converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs on linux

Tags: python

is there any way to  converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs on linux
i know py2exe and pyinstall will work well on windows
but i only has linux Environment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable

Comment: @James Khoury thanks i will have a look

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to convert it to a windows executable on a linux platform? Anyway, I'd say you have two options:

- Use py2exe with wine (a Windows emulator). I've done this, and it works
- If that is not possible, you could try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). I haven't tried it, but it seems to be sort of the same, but multi-platform

Answer (score 1):

cx_Freeze will do you the job.
http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @timger It looks like you need to install libssl-dev first.