# What programming languages come with windows 10 by default (no install required)?

Tags: windows

Similar to this question [What programming languages are installed by default on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280102/what-programming-languages-are-installed-by-default-on-windows-7). Is the environment any differnt for Windows 10?

For some programs like MS OFfice you get the VBA, Chrome you would get Javascript, if you activate the Bash for Ubuntu on Windows then you can get bash. Not sure if that is default.

In particular, if you didn't have administration rights over a Windows 10 laptop but needed a programming language... what could you use or do about it?

ie I wanted Ruby installed but I needed our tech team to help me. I want to avoid someone else with higher access but also not breach policy.

Comment: Related: [Languages that Windows supports out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657843/languages-that-windows-supports-out-of-the-box)

Comment: I would think some programming tools would work when run right off a USB drive or just copied to a user-accessible directory (like C/C++ compilers, for example) so you would have some ability to use non-built-in programming tools without having admin rights.

Comment: The only *programming language* included is C#, but unless you want to write the code in Notepad and compile from a command prompt you're going to need to install an IDE. There are several scripting languages available (Powershell, VBScript, and Windows batch).

Comment: The last sentence is the most important one: if you use a corporate computer, you need to ask your boss about installing any "interpreter" or "compiler", and you need to get *permission* to write even the smallest script. In some jobs (but not all of them) that permission could be implicit. Once you are permitted to write a script and need to install an interpreter/compiler, how exactly that happens is an organizational detail (to be discussed with your boss).

Comment: Cheers all. I've gone and read some of those related questions but wasn't sure if things had changed in the 5+ years since they were asked. Not sure why I've attracted down votes.

Answer (score 8):

Out of the box no install solutions include:

(To be written using text file editing software like the preinstalled notepad)

1. Batch (.bat)
2. Visual basic script (.vbs)
3. HTML (.html)
4. CSS (^Use a style tag for the HTML doc)
5. JavaScript (.js)

Some quick gets include:

1. Bash (Ubuntu from Windows Store)
2. AutoHotKey (from autohotkey.com)
3. #Code (Windows Store. Apparently supports 12 different languages)

Hope this helps!

Edit: If you really wanna try, you can edit .exe files directly but yeesh.

Edit 2: repl.it is a website that lets you code in tons of different languages, possibly Ruby. With repl.it you can do all the things I've listed and more! (As long as you have alright internet.)

Comment: To be a little picky: It's not JavaScript but JScript.

Answer (score 0):

> what could you use

You could use pretty much any languages. Any compiled executables looks the same to the OS as any other.

The only catch is that some languages' runtime libraries are quite big, so it's common for smaller programs not to include the entire language runtime and instead expects it to be preinstalled on the machine to keep its own download size small.

However, even high level scripting languages that requires huge runtime support libraries can often be packaged into standalone executable, so that you don't need to install the runtime yourself.

Ultimately it depends on what you wanted to do. If you wanted to just make simple scripts, probably .bat scripts will do just fine. If you wanted something simple and fast, then you can write native executable in C, otherwise if you want to do something a bit more complex and you're fine with the larger download size if you can keep your own program simple, or if you can later get admin to preinstall your preferred runtime on your target machines, then high level languages like Python or Ruby would be great options.

Answer (score -1):

Although windows core is written in C and extended primarily with C# and C++ it doesn't actually come natively with a scripting environment for those languages. You would have to install IDE's that will definitely not be allowed by any corporate policy.
The only language that comes with the os really is shell language, which isn't really a language but more like an object call sheet. You call objects, mostly small executables, and give them some parameters to perform certain actions on other objects. There are two. The simple shell often wrongly called dos which you can access with CMD.exe. Power shell is the second built in shell scripting environment with .net access that allows  you to virtually write anything using any natively installed library in the system.
I'd first have a look at powershell as it's very close to the native c and c# languages and comes with windows out of the box and can be extended to compile any script into executables.

Both shell environments can do quite a lot of things before needing administrator rights by using system objects that have already been given permission to execute their code. There will be a limit though which usually is encountered when you try to change system settings or meddle with files in system folders. The work around would be to keep everything in the user documents folder and don't try to meddle with system files or settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).