# Cross-compile Python in Ubuntu to run on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, compilation, cross-compiling

I need to compile a python script for a project. I am programming it in my Linux(Ubuntu) environment, and I need to have the finalized product be a .exe file to run on windows.

--**It needs to be compiled so that the windows machine receiving it doesn't need to have a python environment installed on it.**--

I know pyinstaller can compile scripts into executables, but it doesn't do cross-compiling. 
An older version of pyinstaller does, but it only supports python2.6

The problem is, I need python 2.7 or 3.+ for my project.

Is there a program I can use to accomplish this, or maybe a workaround... something?

Comment: What's wrong with using wine?

Comment: What do you mean? Using it how?

Comment: ... Using it to run the Windows version of pyinstaller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-compiling a Python script on Linux into a Windows executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable)