# Cross-Compiling Python From Linux into Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, compilation, cross-compiling

In a linux enviroment, how would one freeze a python script into an executable. The answers at [Cross-compiling a Python script on Linux into a Windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable) as PyInstaller killed the referenced feature. I have also tried py2exe with wine to no avail. An suggestions on what works?

Comment: install a windows virtual box and then use pyinstaller in the virtualbox (you will need to install python + all packages in the virtual box) (in my experience pyinstaller is much easier to work with than py2exe most of the time you just do `> C:\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.py my_main.py`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-compiling a Python script on Linux into a Windows executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable)