# How do i make a Windows Executable from python using Linux?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use Linux for programming and i want to make a Windows executable using python 2.7 on Linux.How can i do this? I tried installing bbfreeze but get an error while doing python setup.py install.
Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have python-dev installed to newest version

Comment: What error did you get? Please always include all error messages to your SO questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable