# Pyinstaller - convert python to exe from Linux

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

I want to convert one `.py` file to `.exe` from Linux Ubuntu. I found pyinstaller for this. But when pyinstaller runs from Linux it makes file executable only for Linux and when pyinstaller runs from Windows it makes .exe file for Windows. I want to convert .exe file from Linux for Windows. So how can i make it? I need an instruction.

**P.S:** if i cannot do it with pyinstaller, please write other tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-compiling a Python script on Linux into a Windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable)

Comment: @Lodi that question isn't answered completely

Comment: Yes, it is. It says that you'll need to use a tool to virtually use windows inside linux. There's no other way

Comment: Take a look here https://www.andreafortuna.org/technology/how-to-cross-compile-a-python-script-into-a-windows-executable-on-linux/ , This article teaches how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to use Docker, that may be an easy enough way to do it. The relevant docker images [can be found here](https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller).

From the documentation there:

> There are two containers, one for Linux and one for Windows builds.
>   The Windows builder runs Wine inside Ubuntu to emulate Windows in
>   Docker.
>
> To build your application, you need to mount your source code into the
>   `/src/` volume.
>
> The source code directory should have your `.spec` file that PyInstaller
>   generates. If you don't have one, you'll need to run PyInstaller once
>   locally to generate it.
>
> If the src folder has a `requirements.txt` file, the packages will be
>   installed into the environment before PyInstaller runs.
>
> For example, in the folder that has your source code, `.spec` file and
>   `requirements.txt`:
>
> ```
> docker run -v "$(pwd):/src/" cdrx/pyinstaller-windows
> ```
>
> will build your
>   PyInstaller project into `dist/windows/`. The `.exe` file will have the
>   same name as your `.spec` file.
>
> ```
> docker run -v "$(pwd):/src/" cdrx/pyinstaller-linux
> ```
>
> will build your PyInstaller project into `dist/linux/`. The binary will have the same
>   name as your `.spec` file.