# Easiest way to create executable for windows from a Python on Linux environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, wine

I want to make a Python 3.6 program which I develop on Ubuntu into an executable for windows. From what I searched online it seems I will need pyinstaller over wine. If there is an easier way, you can stop reading here, and suggest another way.
I tried to follow the answer on [Cross-compiling a Python script on Linux into a Windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable)
but then I got to the part after downloading the python. I downloaded the latest python version for windows which was the file **python-3.7.3-amd64.exe** which is not an MSI like in the answer on the link above which use **python-2.7.10.msi**. What would be the replacement for the cmd in the link for:

> wine msiexec /i python-2.7.10.msi /L*v log.txt

?
Do the other steps have to change?
In general, is it more recommendable to use python 2.7 to create the exe, can't my program have incompatibility issues with it (since i used python3.6 on my Linux for the development)?

Answer (score 1):

It's more recommended to use same version of python to avoid bugs.

Maybe check this link : https://askubuntu.com/a/1133860
Apparently installer for python3 does not work well with wine, but you can use zip available on official site.

For more information about python version and wine, check this link : https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7578