# How can I cross compile a python script into an executable using Mac?

Tags: python

On a Mac I haven't been able to cross compile my python code into a stand-alone executable. Using Pyinstaller or Py2exe only compiles it into a file thats supported by Mac, I think this is because cross compiling is not supported, but I saw a post saying you can use Wine, Im not sure how to go about doing it since I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra

Comment: I think you're misusing "cross compile" here. Python is interpreted. You're trying to *package* an executable, not compile one

Comment: Hi [Check This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950971/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-linux-into-a-windows-executable)
It seems to be working.

Answer (score -2):

**Hello, check out this options:**

**Single executable (all platforms)**

- [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) - the most active(Could also be used with `PyQt`)
- [fbs](https://build-system.fman.io) - if you chose Qt above

**Single executable (Windows)**

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) - used to be the most popular

**Single executable (Linux)**

- [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) - works the same way like py2exe but targets Linux platform

**Single executable (Mac)**

- [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) - again, works like py2exe but targets Mac OS

Hope it help. Good luck.